# An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook. Please try again

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I use `SharePoint 2013` and I use BI web site in SharePoint.

I Configured `Power Pivot Service` in SharePoint 2013.

I upload my excel file that contain Power Pivot report.

When I open my Excel file in Share point document and select `Refresh Selected Connection` from `Data` menu,

[image]

I get this error :

[image]

```
External Data Refresh Failed
An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook. 
Please try again. 

We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook. 
The following connections failed to refresh:
```

I set my `SSS ID` in `Excel Services Authentication Settings` in my excel report.

[image]

And I configure my `SSS` like this :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I Found this link [PowerPivot 2013 for SharePoint - "External Data Refresh Failed" using Interactive Data Refresh via "Use the authenticated user's account"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/04/02/3550012.aspx) but it not work in my case.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I have the same issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I changed my way. I found that i should not use this way. Better way is create report file Online in share point and separate excel file with data and excel file with report in two separate file.